# What is the purpose of declaring activities?

Tags: android

I'm not asking how to declare or use an activity, I'm perfectly fine with that. What I am really wondering is why do activities even exist as declared elements, what is the purpose behind them? Does forcing me to declare the elements I use in two places (manifest and the code itself) somehow supposed to improve security?

Comment: This is more a question of why the Manifest file is necessary at all. If you understand that, it'll become clearer why certain declarations are needed inside the manifest file. Permissions, Application meta data, package information, etc etc are integral in how an app is built by the system. Check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In code, you have just ordinary Java classes. The export tool would have to detect which ones extend `Activity`, or `FragmentActivity`, or any subclass of those. And some may just be abstract. Anyway, Android needs a list of all available `Activity`s.

By declaring them in the manifest, you have the opportunity to declare additional attributes and metadata that Android needs to know.

Which `Intent` filters are available? Which mode do you want to start your `Activity`s in? When to launch which `Activity`? Android needs to know that.

**Edit:** Not to forget the permissions that are necessary to start single `Activity`s, as well as the icons and labels - all that must be known.

Answer (score 2):

Activities are declared in Manifest so Android OS can perform a lookup when handling an Intent.

A most outstanding idea behind that is that you can make an Activity from another application a part of your Activities stack. If another application's Manifest allows that.